# Why isn't my `load` function getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to preload certain images that I have decorated with an attribute and I'm wondering if you guys can help me figure out what's going wrong here. I have

```
          var barlen = $('#SSWEprogressbar').width(),
              $elems = $('[data-srcurl]'),
                   n = $elems.length;
          for ( var k = 0; k < n; ++k )
          {
              var $elem = $($elems[k]);
              var img = new Image(),
                  url = $elem.attr('data-srcurl');

              $(img).load(function(){
                 console.log("we're here");//TEST
                 $('#SSWEloaderfront').attr('src',url);

                 $('#SSWEloadprogress').width(k/n*barlen + "px");
              });
              var srctgt = $elem.attr('data-srctgt');
              if ( srctgt == "srcattr" )
              {
                $elem.attr('src',url);
              }
              else if ( srctgt == "bgimg" )
              {
                $elem.css('background-image',url);
              }
          }
```

and then

```
console.log("we're here");//TEST
```

isn't being invoked. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `url` when this runs?

Comment: @DelightedD0D it will be a relative url to an image in a folder

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting the src attribute on the img element, so the load will never fire. You need to add $(img).attr('src', url);